# Why does the Vigor skill bonus from equipment not increase Blessed Hammer damage?

Tags: diablo-ii

This is my damage when boots on.
[image]

This is my damage when boots off.
[image]

**Vigor is synergy for Blessed Hammer, why doesn't the boots increase my damage?**

Comment: Worth noting: that screen on the left is often referred to, within the community, as the “Lying Character Screen.” It’s right about this synergy, but there are plenty of things that don’t get factored into that number but actually *do* enhance your damage. The only numbers on that screen that are *never* wrong are your level and experience (in one patch, even the latter could get messed up, but that was a very rare bug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, synergies only work for the base skill points invested into the skill. So even though the actual skill "Vigor" is being enhanced by the boots, any synergies with the skill is not.

The only way to increase "Blessed Hammer"'s damage, once you have maxed the hard skill points (from levels and quests) into the synergies, is to get soft skill points (from equipment) that add to "Blessed Hammer" (or +combat or +all skills).

This is a safety to prevent synergies from spiking out of control with +all skills items.

Comment: Thanks, just a side question, what would be a good enough soft skill points from items, for blessed hammer, I got a mace with +3 to blessed hammer, is that normal or very good? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Skill bonuses from items don't affect synergies.